# fancybox does not show php generated image

Tags: php, image, fancybox

I have the next problem. I was working some times with fancybox plugin and it was ok until I had to use cms which gives me images as code.  Like this :

```
}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?����m"M_sy�S�����.Y�u d�0z{�g�2]IZ��',���x��G��m!HY�E�� ������� ����8o�.r�__�Ux�l5'F�l�.��gy�cK3��8��)�i�������᧐$:e�d�"#�i]^�?]��5+]Q��/�E���ᰱ����/
```

By itself it shows images normally, but I wonder if there is any chance for me to see normal picture? Here is the code that I use:

```
<a class="gallery_item" rel="gallery" href=".../image.php?photogalleryitemid=616&y=200">
<img width="255" height="129" border="0" src=".../image.php?photogalleryitemid=616&x=255&y=129">
</a><!-- many of them with different id's -->

$("a.gallery_item").fancybox();
```

Comment: You miss the msot important, your php script that display image ^^

Comment: looks like the php script is not sending a "Content-Type" header

Comment: I dont have access to php. And all the time it displays images just fine. Firebug says `Content-Type image/jpeg`

Comment: I'm agree with Dale !

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support (FAQ tab) No. 5